# Update paperclip attachment with a same name file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a model with paperclip attachment. When I try to update the model with another image, everything works fine except if the new file has the same name that the old one.

I guess paperclip doesn't understand that it's a new file even if the filename is the same.

Do you have a idea to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find an elegant solution to this, but here is how I got it to work:

Have an attr_accessor boolean flag on your model, and when true call the Paperclip save method to force an update.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   # paperclip attachment
   has_attached_file :image, { ... }

   attr_accessor :creative_uploaded

   before_save :upload_new_creative_if_necessary

   private

   def upload_new_creative_if_necessary
     if creative_uploaded
       # force update of the creative
       image.save
     end
   end
end
```

In my controller, when a post occurs with a file, I set that flag:

```
@my_instance = MyModel.new( params[:my_model] )
@my_instance.creative_uploaded if params[:my_model][:image]

# ActiveRecord save/handle validations logic as normal
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer indeed works.  However; I didn't like how tied it was to a specific field and actually had many places that I needed this functionality.  The below concern should work in most cases (it makes an assumption that you don't have any non-paperclip columns using file_name in their name).

```
module AttachmentUpdatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :check_for_and_save_images
  end

  def check_for_and_save_images
    return if self.new_record?
    self.changed_attributes.each do |attr|
      attr_name = attr[0].to_s
      next unless attr_name.include?('file_name') # Yes, this is an assumption
      image_col = attr_name.gsub('_file_name','')
      self.send(image_col).save
    end
  end

end
```